# "Density contour plot"—plot solution surface using color

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot the solution of an equation in three variables via a color map, thus combining the functions of ContourPlot3D and DensityPlot.

That is, I have a plot of the form

```
ContourPlot3D[F(x,y,z)==0,{x,x1,x2},{y,y1,y2},{z,z1,z2}]
```

but I think it would look much better as a plot in (x,y) space where each point is assigned a color corresponding to a z value. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Have you seen `SliceContourPlot3D[]` and `SliceDensityPlot3D[]`?

Comment: I don't think this is what I want....looks like this plots a function of three variables on a surface, whereas I'm simply looking to transform a surface into a 2D density plot.

Comment: Okay, so in the case of there being two or more $z$ values corresponding to an $x,y$ pair, what do you want to do?

Comment: That's a good question. Let's say that I've constrained the bounds on x, y, and z such that there's only one solution for any x and y, so that this won't be a problem

Comment: Do you have a sample `F[x, y, z]` and an appropriate domain in mind, so that we can try something out with actual examples?